# PCA on Imbalanced data

Tags: pca

1. Is it appropriate to apply PCA on imbalanced data
2. After applying PCA,by applying under sampling method will improve performance
3. What are the implications by applying PCA and subsequently under sampling method on imbalanced data

Answer (score 3):

Note that PCA is an unsupervised method.

In most cases, when we say the data is imbalanced, we are talking about the prediction label has skewed distribution.

1. We can run PCA on any data, even the data is not 'evenly distributed'. PCA just rotate data, and optionally, maps data into a lower dimensional space.
2. It is not clear on what is the performance of the PCA. If we are working on data without label. A related concept is "Explained variance in PCA", if data is not evenly distributed, we may able to use less component to cover more variance. But I think that is not what you are asking for.
3. Again PCA is an unsupervised method and is not using any information on label. So, it is possible that if you run PCA, and the classifier performance is completely destroyed (for example, a dummy feature has huge variance).

Comment: Like after applying pca and undersampling will the classifier performance metrics like recall will improve

Comment: There is no theorem that says that certain transformation will improve a random classifier's performance. It's a matter of trial and error.

Comment: @Ruser It is an old topic but it could help others:
A paper answers your question : [Class imbalance and its effect on PCA preprocessing](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1504/IJKESDP.2014.064265).

I quote:  "This study proved the fact that **when there is a directional difference between the minority class and majority class principal axes**, the classification performance and reprojection error **are affected in PCA reduced subspace.**"